# Conversion of varchar data type to datetime in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to run a stored procedure on SSMS, I develop on SSIS and I call it on SSMS, I have a problem with data conversion, here are the settings I made and the error

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

when I run it on ssms like this:

> exec dbo.PS_00790_SyntheseDG_Commission_EchF_InfoTechq
> @DateDebPer = '01/01/2015'
> , @DateFinPer = '31/12/2020'

it works, but i want to run it from ssis_catalogue with an ssis package

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an ambigious date format. If you *are* using string for dates, then use `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`. SSIS, however, has a `datetime` datatype, so use that instead and don't suffer any implicit conversions in the first place.

Comment: I did the same for another stored procedure and it works! but not on this one :(

Comment: Did *what* @wassimremmas ?

Comment: the same settings I made in screenshot

Comment: But in the screenshots the datatype of your variables is a **string**... Those are clearly dates, so use the `datetime` datatype.

Comment: yes i did that too, and i also have the same error message

Comment: If the datatype of your variable, `[User::DateDebPer]` is a `datetime` and the parameter is configured as a `date` in the Execute T-SQL Task parameters then the problem has nothing to do with SSIS and the problem is in your Procedure's definition, @wassimremmas . You should be posting the definition of that instead.